# getting CS0029 error when using StringBuilder

Tags: c#

I'm trying to refresh my knowledge regarding c# and came accross this problem,

---

Have the function StringChallenge(str) take the str parameter being passed and return a compressed version of the string using the Run-length encoding algorithm. This algorithm works by taking the occurrence of each repeating character and outputting that number along with a single character of the repeating sequence. For example: "wwwggopp" would return 3w2g1o2p. The string will not contain any numbers, punctuation, or symbols.

---

and my code is

```
using System;
using System.Text;
class MainClass {

  public static string StringChallenge(string str) {

    // code goes here  

    var newString = new StringBuilder();
    var result = new StringBuilder();


    foreach (var c in str){
      if (newString.Length == 0 || newString[newString.Length - 1] == c){
        newString.Append(c);
      }
      else{
        result.Append($"{newString.Length}{newString[0]}");
        newString.Clear();
        newString.Append(c);
      }
    }

    if (newString.Length > 0){
      result.Append($"{newString.Length}{newString[0]}");
    }

    return result;

  }

  static void Main() {  
    // keep this function call here
    Console.WriteLine(StringChallenge(Console.ReadLine()));
  } 

}
```

please help. thank you!

Comment: instead of `return result;` do `return result.ToString();`

Comment: it works! thank you!